# ReactJS componentDidMount + render

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, reactjs

I am currently using react to create d3 visualizations.  I'm a little confused about the relationship between the `render` and `componenetDidMount` methods (is methods the proper term?).  Here is what I have (I excluded some code for simplicity):

```
var Chart = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function () {
    var el = this.getDOMNode();
    console.log(el);
    d3Chart.create(el, {
        width: '500',
        height: '300'
    }, this.getChartState(),this.getAccessState);
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="row pushdown">
                <div className="d3-block">
                    <div className="Chart" />
                </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

On line 3, `el` gets assigned `this.getDOMNode();` which always points to the top level element in the render function (`div "row pushdown"`).  So does `this.getDOMNode()` always refer to the top level element in the render function? What I'm actually trying to do is render the d3 chart within the innermost `div` (`.Chart`).  I first tried doing `this.getDOMNode().find('.Chart')` but that didn't work.

First question: I know that I shouldn't be trying to touch the real DOM here but how would I go about selecting something further down on the VirtualDOM?

Second question:  I know that, given I am very new to this, am probably doing this the wrong way.  Can you suggest a better method here?

Third question:  I want to add a chart legend in a sibling `div` of `".Chart"`.  Should I be creating a new component for this?  Or in my d3Chart can I use selectors to do this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

P.S.  I have one side question:

I've seen people use `React.render(<Chart />,document.body)` instead of using `React.createElement` within that.  Could somebody explain to me the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `getDOMNode()` returns the outermost DOM element that was `render`ed.

A1. I'd suggest you use a `ref` attribute ([documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-attribute)) which provides a reference to the DOM element for later usage:

```
<div ref="chart" className="Chart" />

componentDidMount: function() {
    // << you can get access to the element by name as shown below
    var chart = this.refs.chart; 
    // do what you want here ...
}
```

A2. While ultimately you might want to refactor your code into multiple components, there's nothing wrong with what you've created (assuming you try the `ref` option mentioned above).

A3. As the legend would represent a very different piece of functionality (and isolated), creating a distinct component would be typical React. You might still have a `Chart` component that contains both the actual chart visualization but also has another component which displays a legend. It's a nice separation of concerns. But, you could also consider a Flux model where each component listens for changes and renders its visuals completely independently. If they work tightly together, a Flux model may not make as much sense.

Side: Using JSX, you might see:

```
React.render(<App />, document.body)
```

That would just render the `App` into the document body contents.

That is equivalent to precompiled JSX:

```
React.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.body);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I have to comments/questions:

A3: My legend and chart will be tied to the same data, so if I was to update the state with new data, both would need to be updated.  I'm going to look into what a Flux model is but they do work tightly together.

Side:  So the only difference is whether or not it's precompiled?  The latter being the precompiled version.

Comment: Side: yes, that's the only difference.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note...as of v0.13.  `componentDidMount()` may not yet have `this.refs` available.  From the changelog:

`ref` resolution order has changed slightly such that a ref to a component is available immediately after its `componentDidMount` method is called; this change should be observable only if your component calls a parent component's callback within your `componentDidMount`, which is an anti-pattern and should be avoided regardless

Answer (score 1):

`this.refs` is perfect to find any dom node in react component life cycle using `ReactDOM` library. Install `react-dom` with NPM or include the JS in your page.

So your entire component code should look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var Chart = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function () {
    var el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.chartComp);
    console.log(el);
    d3Chart.create(el, {
        width: '500',
        height: '300'
    }, this.getChartState(),this.getAccessState);
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="row pushdown">
                <div className="d3-block">
                    <div ref="chartComp" className="Chart" />
                </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that as of React v15.0 `getDOMNode()` is removed (deprecated since v0.13) and can no longer be used.

edit: There's a thorough explanation about deprecation of `getDOMNode()` and introduction of `React.findDOMNode(component)` (that you should use instead) in the following answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30191683/6223301

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the explanation you provide?

Comment: Added link description. Stumbled upon this question yesterday and actually wanted to comment the accepted answer but am unable to do that yet (missing rep). So this comment not 100% related to the original question, can remove the comment if not deemed to be beneficial.

Answer (score -1):

rendering go from parent to childrem. So `componentDidMount` may not have `refs` to child nodes instead put `setTimeout` function so all child node got rendered and refs will be available for actions