# React.js: The difference between findDOMNode and getDOMNode

Tags: reactjs

Could somebody tell me what's the difference between

```
React.findDOMNode(this.refs.email).value
```

and

```
this.refs.email.getDOMNode().value
```

They are doing the same thing - getting the value of element, but where should I use which one.

Comment: It was mentioned here: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/10/react-v0.13.html#new-features

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`component.getDOMNode()` is deprecated as of React 0.13:

> Added new top-level API `React.findDOMNode(component)`, which should be
>   used in place of `component.getDOMNode()`. The base class for ES6-based
>   components will not have `getDOMNode`. This change will enable some more
>   patterns moving forward.

via http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/10/react-v0.13.html#new-features

It will likely be removed in a future version of React (but don't quote me on that, because I can't find a good reference).

---

#### EDIT: Updated to reflect React 0.14

`getDOMNode()` throws a warning in 0.13 and 0.14, and it will be removed completely in 0.15:

> With each returned DOM node, we've added a `getDOMNode` method for backwards 
>   compatibility that will work with a warning until 0.15.

via https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#new-deprecations-introduced-with-a-warning

Also note that calling `findDOMNode` or `getDOMNode` is no longer necessary for React DOM components as of 0.14:

> The other big change we’re making in this release is exposing refs to DOM components as the DOM node itself. That means: we looked at what you can do with a ref to a React DOM component and realized that the only useful thing you can do with it is call `this.refs.giraffe.getDOMNode()` to get the underlying DOM node. Starting with this release, `this.refs.giraffe` *is* the actual DOM node. **Note that refs to custom (user-defined) components work exactly as before; only the built-in DOM components are affected by this change.**

via https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#dom-node-refs

---

Relevant code and commits from the React repo on GitHub:

- https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a6d03f36a4a9e7c1e6688bdba89656f2e20e7df8/src/modern/class/ReactComponent.js#L101-L104
- https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/b46a6ce4bb8d6087ed424764f41fe4b8e248b3b4
- https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/fb23276178b28fdcb75aa22be013a91755f7ad0a

Answer (score 1):

The second one is the old API for accessing a refs DOM node, and the first one is the new way. So if you're using a recent version of React, you should use the first.