# How can I convert React Element to Html element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reactjs, element

Now I've using ag-Grid that can create custom renderer for each data cells but it's required Html elements

For example they're an Elements that can be created by calling document.createElement()

But I want to use React element as custom renderer for my convenient

Don't sure that I can do that or not ?

Comment: So if I got it right, you are creating a custom cell renderer like this: `cellRenderer: reactCellRendererFactory(MyCustomCellRenderer)`, right? And your question is if you can use React components in the jsx that the render method of MyCustomCellRenderer component returns?

Comment: @Smilev, that is exactly what I'd like to know. At the very least, it seems that cannot be done in the function version of a cell renderer, Can that be done in the component form of the cellRenderer?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `getDOMNode` for example: `this.refs.giraffe.getDOMNode()`, or:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
...
const submitBtn = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.submitButton)
```

But that way has some deprecation issues, more here: [React.js: The difference between findDOMNode and getDOMNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190608/react-js-the-difference-between-finddomnode-and-getdomnode)

Answer (score 0):

There's a new React way in ag-grid for this purpose. It's quite recent so you have to update your ag-grid module. Instead of using `cellRenderer` use `cellRendererFactory` to which you can pass React component directly. Source: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#react-cell-rendering

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist anymore in docs? is this still possible?

Comment: new url: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#react-cell-rendering

Comment: Yes it's still possible. Be aware that this might affect performance quite badly if you have quite a lot of rows. After doing dozens of grids with AG for 1year+ I can really say it's a pile of **** :). But ok if you don't have to do much with it.