# `$(...).fullCalendar is not a function` in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, fullcalendar, components

So I've read about 15 different posts that have similar issues, but they all seem to be either caused by improperly loading jQuery or improperly loading fullcalendar. However, I know I'm loading both into my component (whether or not I'm doing it properly I'm unsure). I'm using the `fullcalendar` npm in my `package.json`.

My component:

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import fc from 'fullcalendar';

export default class DailyEvents extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(fc)
        console.log($('#calendar'))
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar();
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        );
    }
}
```

The output I get from `console.log(fc)` is:

```
Object {version: "3.4.0", internalApiVersion: 9, views: Object, intersectRanges: function, applyAll: function…}
AgendaView:function ()
BasicView:function ()
Calendar:function (el, overrides)
Class:function Class()
CoordCache:function (options)
DayGrid:function ()
DayTableMixin:Object
DragListener:function (options)
EmitterMixin:Object
Grid:function (view)
ListenerMixin:Object
Model:function ()
MonthView:function ()
Promise:Object
RenderQueue:function (waitsByNamespace)
Scroller:function (options)
TaskQueue:function ()
TimeGrid:function ()
View:function (calendar, viewSpec)
applyAll:function applyAll(functions, thisObj, args)
capitaliseFirstLetter:function capitaliseFirstLetter(str)
compareByFieldSpec:function compareByFieldSpec(obj1, obj2, fieldSpec)
compareByFieldSpecs:function compareByFieldSpecs(obj1, obj2, fieldSpecs)
computeGreatestUnit:function computeGreatestUnit(start, end)
createObject:function createObject(proto)
cssToStr:function cssToStr(cssProps)
dataAttrPrefix:""
datepickerLocale:function (localeCode, dpLocaleCode, dpOptions)
debounce:function debounce(func, wait, immediate)
divideDurationByDuration:function divideDurationByDuration(dur1, dur2)
divideRangeByDuration:function divideRangeByDuration(start, end, dur)
durationHasTime:function durationHasTime(dur)
flexibleCompare:function flexibleCompare(a, b)
formatDate:function formatDate(date, formatStr)
formatRange:function formatRange(date1, date2, formatStr, separator, isRTL)
getClientRect:function getClientRect(el, origin)
getContentRect:function getContentRect(el, origin)
getOuterRect:function getOuterRect(el, origin)
getScrollbarWidths:function getScrollbarWidths(el)
htmlEscape:function htmlEscape(s)
internalApiVersion:9
intersectRanges:function intersectRanges(subjectRange, constraintRange)
intersectRects:function intersectRects(rect1, rect2)
isBgEvent:function isBgEvent(event)
isInt:function isInt(n)
locale:function (localeCode, newFcOptions)
locales:Object
log:function ()
moment:function ()
multiplyDuration:function multiplyDuration(dur, n)
oldMomentFormat:function oldMomentFormat(mom, formatStr)
parseFieldSpecs:function parseFieldSpecs(input)
pluckEventDateProps:function pluckEventDateProps(event)
preventDefault:function preventDefault(ev)
proxy:function proxy(obj, methodName)
queryMostGranularFormatUnit:function queryMostGranularFormatUnit(formatStr)
sourceFetchers:Array(0)
sourceNormalizers:Array(0)
touchMouseIgnoreWait:500
version:"3.4.0"
views:Object
warn:function ()
__proto__:Object
```

So I'm pretty sure that's right.

And what I get from `console.log($('#calendar'))` is:

```
[div#calendar, context: document, selector: "#calendar"]
0:div#calendar
context:document
length:1
selector:"#calendar"
__proto__:Object(0)
```

That looks pretty good to me too.

I have no idea where I'm going wrong...

**Edit:**

The solution is to add the following to your plugins in `webpack.config.js`:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery",
    "moment": "moment"
})
```

I don't understand it but https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/349#issuecomment-250865512 for further reading.

Comment: Better use `refs`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662624/reactjs-componentdidmount-render

Comment: Used refs initially. Same result. I changed it to id to make sure I wasn't screwing something up with jquery

Comment: Using refs would attempt to solve finding the element, right? But I'm obviously finding the element as is indicated by my console output

Comment: i'm not too sure but it might be a webpack problem. Here's another post i found
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321399/use-fullcalendar-with-webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that´s related to webpack configuration.

You should:

- Declare jQuery and fullCalendar as externals and add them globally
- Use this configuration https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/349#issuecomment-250865512